# nvd3.js - time series date issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am attempting to plot some time series data using the nvd3 library. For some reason nvd3 renders big gaps between each month.

My dates have a format like this:

```
20110101
20110102
20110103
```

I believe that the formatting string should be `"%Y%m%d"`.

I have read other nvd3 posts and people refer to a setting a formatting function within `chart.xAxis.tickFormat` like this:

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
            return d3.time.format('%Y%m%d')(new Date(d.toString()));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
});
```

However that returns `"0NaNNaNNaN"` for each date value.

I have tried an alternative:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d");

chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
        return format.parse(d.toString());                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
});
```

This seems to create the right label values, but the data still displays improperly.

I created a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGyKF/3/)

Comment: If you add some logging to your jsfiddle, you'll see that some of the values that are passed to `tickFormat` aren't valid dates in that format. Part of the problem may be that the dates in your JSON are numbers. Have you tried to encode them as strings?

Comment: You can see that @LarsKotthoff is talking about here: http://jsfiddle.net/jJb7M/1/ The code in there will allow you to get a Date object from your x values.